# getting black screen when video is played in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, video

i am designing an app for android using cordova in which i have to take a video and play that video on click.i am able to store the video in sdcard and that video get played only when enlarge button on right side of player is click i am not able to play video after getting set in particular tag of page,i get black screen that is i can hear audio but i am not able to view video i can only view video on click of enlarge button.Please help me to solve this issue.

.html

```
 <div id="idVedioShowdiv" style="display:none"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:20px!important;"></div>
      <div style="display:block;" id="idVediocapturediv"> <img src="images/Capture.png" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="captureVedio();"/></div>

        <div class="result-block" style="display:none">
        <div style="color:White">Capture Result:</div> <span id="capture-result" style="color:White"></span><br/>
        <span id="capture-data"></span><br/>
        <!--<div id="audio-result"  style="color:White">Play Vedio</div>-->

        </div>
```

.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function captureSuccessVedio(mediaFiles) {
 try{
     alert(mediaFiles.length);
      var i, len;
      var formatSuccess = function (mediaFile) {
          document.getElementById('capture-data').innerHTML =
                "Duration: <strong>" + mediaFile.duration + "</strong><br/>";
      };

      for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {

          document.getElementById('capture-result').innerHTML = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

      };
      Playvedio();
     }catch(ex){
    }
  }


  function captureErrorVedio(error) {

  }

  function captureVedio() {
  try{
      navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccessVedio, captureErrorVedio, { limit: 1 });
       }catch(ex){
    }
  }





  function Playvedio() {
  try{

      var path = $('#capture-result').text();
     $('#idVedioShowdiv').show();
      $('#idVedioShowdiv').append('<div class="mainPhotodiv"><div class="photodiv" id="idvedioDiv"><div class="mainPhotodiv"><div class="deleteImg"><img id="ImgIdDelete" src="images/delete.png" alt="" onclick="deleteVedio(this)" style="width: 100%" /></div><div class="photodiv" id="idvedioDiv"><video style="width: 100%"  poster="http://196.38.94.34:9091/Images/PlayVedio.png" controls><source src="' + path + '" type="video/mp4"></video></div></div></video></div></div>');
           }
      catch(ex)
      {
     alert("err:::"+ex);
      }
  }
  function deleteVedio(ImgTagVedio) {
  $(ImgTagVedio).parents('.mainPhotodiv').remove();
   }




        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use [cordova-open](https://github.com/disusered/cordova-open) plugin to open audio, video, and images with applications installed on a device.

Answer (score 0):

this is for AndroidWebView update. uninstall android Web View update from settings>app>system apps>android web view.
it will solve the problem.